# Django ORM Count group and subgroup

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

In my django project i had a table with a column named 'key_id'. Until today i had to group different values of this values, count it and display the largest result.
I did this:

```
maxpar = temp_test_keywords.objects.filter(main_id=test_id).values('key_id').annotate(total=Count('key_id')).order_by('-total').first()
maxMax = maxpar['total']
```

all done.
Today, we deceide to add another field to table, 'key_group'(could be 1,2,3,4) and now i have to use the same query for group and count max key_id field but related also for key_group.

For example before if in my table there was 5 record with key_id=187 and 3 with 112 my query had to return 5, now if for that 5 records 4 contain 'key_group=1' and one = 2 query have to return 4

Hope i was clear

Thanks in advance
Luke

Comment: So you basically want an extra *filtering*?

Comment: Try `values('key_id', 'key_group')`. That should result in a GROUP BY on both columns, I think.